# Is there any simplification for the following code?

Tags: javascript

So I made this function that checks if x is a power of y and I was wondering if it could be written in a simpler fashion

I've already done all I could do to simplify it but I was wondering if it could be simpler

```
  let IsPowerOf = (x, y) => {
  let l = x,
   n = 0;
  while (l % y == 0) {
    l / = y;
    n++;
  }
  if (Math.pow(y, n) == x)
    console.log(" true ");
  else
    console.log("false");
};
```

it should still work if there are any simplifications made

Comment: You could use a ternary operator.

Comment: I'd suggest posting on codereview.stackexchange.com. This type of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, unfortunately.

Comment: Why are `k` and `n` globals?

Comment: Use logarithms instead of repeated divisions.

Comment: `l -= k` doesn't look like the code is working as expected in the first place.

Comment: Belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bergi I had to do that for when I was logging each variable for some reason it kept telling me that it was "Undefined"

Comment: @jrex51 If you were logging the local variables *inside* the function, then declaring the variables in the local scope should have worked. Notice that initialising `n = 0` only once (not on every call) breaks the functionality.

Comment: @Bergi it worked perfectly fine for me on many different examples the `l -= k` is used to determin how many times it's divided until it can't be divided thus ending the loop

Comment: @jrex51 the `n++` counts how often the number can be divided by `y`. The subtraction makes no sense at all. It really should be `l = k;` (or without the `k` variable, just `l = l / y; n++;` as the loop body).

Comment: @Bergi I see now, guess that one slipped right past me, thanks a lot for letting me know,  much appreciated

Comment: It bothers me that this question is getting DV merely for asking "how do I improve x" instead of the more usual "x doesn't work, how do I fix it".

Comment: @James I actually don't know what I did wrong to get DV except that people said that this belongs in code review other than that I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

A good simplification would be to use logarithms instead. Assuming your browser supports [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Browser_compatibility), you could simply do the following:

```js
function isPowerOf(x, y) {
  return Number.isInteger(Math.log(x) / Math.log(y));
}

console.log(isPowerOf(16, 2));
```

Comment: …and it even works for `isPowerOf(42, 1)`!

Comment: @Bergi that is why I didn't use the log functions, it doesn't serve the purpose and also I wanted to build my own function

Comment: @jrex51 I mean they serve the purpose much better than repeated division, which goes into an infinite loop when you pass `1` as the base.

Comment: @Bergi true, could you perhaps show me how to avoid any infinite loops despite any value I enter?

Comment: @jrex51 It just needs an extra check for `1`. Maybe also disallow negative bases. If you fear problems with accuracy, `if (l == l / y)` will do as well. Considering all these edge cases is hard work, which is why using a logarithm is simpler :-)

Comment: @Bergi got it 
Thanks again :)

Comment: The Problem with the logarithm solution is JS' floating point system. So instead of checking wether the result is integer, you'd need to check it is pretty much an integer, like `n = Math.log(x) / Math.log(y); return Math.abs(Math.round(n) - n) < 1e-15`

Comment: or `return x === Math.pow(y, Math.round(Math.log(x) / Math.log(y)))`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
const isPowerOf = (x, y) => {
  while (x % y == 0) {
    x /= y;
  }
  return x == 1;
};

console.log(isPowerOf(32, 2)); //Should return true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const IsPowerOf = (a, b) => {
  n = parseInt(Math.log(a) / Math.log(b));
  console.log(Math.pow(b, n) == a);
};

IsPowerOf(25,5); // true
IsPowerOf(9,3); // true
IsPowerOf(7,3); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use logarithms and do an integer check by checking if the remainder of division with 1 is equal to 0.

```js
const isPowerOf = (x, y) => (Math.log(x)/Math.log(y)) % 1 === 0;

console.log(isPowerOf(64,8));
console.log(isPowerOf(0.01,0.1));
console.log(isPowerOf(100,11));
```